# Function zero almost everywhere if $\int fg=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Assume $f$ is an integrable function on $\mathbb{R^n}$.  Assume for every bounded continuous function g on $\mathbb{R^n}$, $\int_\mathbb{R^n}fg=0$.  Prove $f$ must equal $0$ almost everywhere.

I am really not sure how to do this problem.  I have tried simple stuff but that is not currently working.

Comment: hint : This is a simple aplication of the classical Du Bois - Raymond lemma  =) .

Comment: @LeandroTavares Any ideas other than that?  I am studying for a comp exam and this is part of a test bank provided to us.  However, we did not discuss this lemma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Since the characteristic function of a closed set is a pointwise non-increasing limit of continuous functions, we can prove by a monotone convergence argument that $\int_{\mathbb R^n}f\chi_F=0$ for each closed subset $F$ of $\mathbb R^n$.
2. For each $\varepsilon>0$ and Borel set $S$ of finite measure, we can find a closed subset $F$ contained in $S$ such that $\lambda_n(S\setminus F)<\varepsilon$. Hence $\int_{\mathbb R^n}f\chi_S=0$ for each Borel subset of finite measure.
3. This can be extended to each Borel subset. Indeed, if  $B$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb R^n$, then $B\cap [0,N]^n$ is a Borel subset of finite measure. By 2., this implies  that $\int_{\mathbb R^n } f\mathbb  1_{ B\cap [0,N]^n}=0$ for each $N$. Then use the dominated convergence theorem for the sequence $\left(f_N\right)_N$ defined by $f_N:= f\mathbb  1_{ B\cap [0,N]^n}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how to extend to non-finite measure Borel subset ?

Comment: @Hua I haved edited in order to add more details.

Comment: Oh, I guess I get it. Thanks !

Comment: Sorry but I wish you could clarify me for another point about the step 2. As far as I know, the "approximation" property used in 2 is doable only in so-called inner regular measure, so this proof works under the assumption that the measure in this problem is inner regular, right ? Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, it works in this more general context.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo Let me make sure I understand how to continue your answer to solve the problem:  We take $B=f^{-1}(0,\infty)$ and get $\int_B f =0$, so $f^+$ is 0 by positive definiteness.  And similarly, $f^-$ is 0 by positive definiteness.  However, how do we know $f^{-1}(0,\infty)$ and $f^{-1}(-\infty,0) are Borel sets?