# How can I show that $f$ must be zero if $\int fg$ is always zero?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f(x)$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and suppose $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx = 0$ for every continuous function $g$ on $[a,b]$. Prove that $f(x)=0$ on $[a,b]$.

I understand that $f(x)$ must be zero otherwise the integral can't possibly be zero for all possible $g$. But, I am not sure how to approach this systematically. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Somewhat similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452835/function-zero-almost-everywhere

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331286/why-does-int-ab-fg-dx-0-imply-that-f-0

Answer (score 7):

Hint: set $g=f$. Then $\int_a^b f^2 \, dx =0$. Can you see why this implies $f=0$?

Comment: Ok, so this shows that when $g=f$, $f=0$, but what about cases when $g\neq f$?

Comment: This is actually enough, because $f^2$ is always going to be greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: You don't need to show something for $g\not = f$. If $f$ would be nonzero, it is sufficient to take $g=f$ to create a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

You can work by assuming, that $f$ is not identically zero. Just for simpliciy, assume that $[a,b]=[-1,1]$ and $f(0)=f_0>0$. Since $f$ is continous, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)>f_{min}>0\quad \forall x\in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$. Since your initial statement shall hold for all $g$, we choose $g = \chi_{-[\epsilon,\epsilon]}(x)$, i.e. $g(x)=1$ if and only if $x\in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$. Then
\begin{align}
\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx &= \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \chi_{-[\epsilon,\epsilon]}(x) dx\\
&=\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon f(x)dx >2\epsilon f_{min}>0
\end{align}
which is a contradiction. Therefore, $f\equiv 0$.

Edit:

I didn't read, that $g$ has to be continous. But you can easily replace $g$ in my proof by a function that is for example a [hat function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) or the [bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) on $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$. It is only important, to have a function that is zero everywhere except for the interval $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ so you can "pick" the specific region where you assume $f$ to be non-zero.