# How can I show $f(x)$ is zero if $\int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx=0$ for each continuous $g$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

[image]

I was thinking doing it by contradiction, but feel there are too many variables to take into account. Any help?

Comment: Let $g(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1128621/215011

Comment: That wasn't much fun.  Assume instead that $\int_a^b f(x)x^n\,dx=0$ for all $n=0,1,2,3, \dots$.  Then show $f$ is the zero function.  More fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a<b$. In the particular case $g=f$ we have $\int_a^b f(x)^2 dx=0$. If $|f(y)|=r>0$ for some $y\in [a,b]$ then for some $e>0$ we have $$x\in [a',b']\implies |f(x)|>r/2,$$ $$ \text { where } a'=\max (a, y-e)\text { and } b'=\min (b,y+e).$$ Observe that $a\leq a'<b'\leq b$. But now $$0=\int_a^b f(x)^2 dx\geq \int _{a'}^{b'} f(x)^2 dx> \int_{a'}^{b'}(r/2)^2 dx=(b'-a')(r/2)^2>0,$$ a contradiction.

Comment: What property allows us to say that is f(y)=r>0 then if x is in the smaller encompassed interval that f(x)>r/2? Is this continuity? It would be cool if I can get a reference to how to do this or the intuition involved with this.

Comment: @user270452. It is the continuity of f.  The intuition is that anything close enough to x gets mapped, by f, into to a small neighborhood of f(x).That is, $\forall e>0 \exists d>0 \forall y\in (x-d,x+d)\cap dom (f) (f(y)\in (f(x)-e,f(x)+e).$ This is the definition of continuity of $f$ at $x$.

Comment: A final clarification: If we are given continuity, we can choose the little e (epsilon) to be anything(any number, in this case r/2) if we say that it is in a certain delta neighborhood?

Comment: For each e we can choose a "d" that satisfies the condition. Generally an  allowable value of d will depend on  e. We usually say "If d is sufficiently small."

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $g=f$. Then prove 
$$
\int_a^bf^2(x)\:dx=0\implies f(x)=0
$$